# How to make sure mouse event can only detect movie clip according to their orders in action script 3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to figure out how to make action on movie clip which can only be detected according to movie clip order.

Follows my code:

```
    test1.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, test1OnClick);

    function test1OnClick (e:MouseEvent) : void
    {
        var currentMC:MovieClip = MovieClip (e.target);
        .....
    }

    test2.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, test2OnClick);
    function test2OnClick (e:MouseEvent) : void
    {
        var currentMC:MovieClip = MovieClip (e.target);
        .....
    }
```

I want to make sure the user can only continue clicking movie clip "test2" after done with "test1".

Comment: What do you mean by "done with test1"? And what do you mean by "can only continue clicking"?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
test1.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, test1OnClick);
```

when the user is done with test 1.

If you want to only be able to click on one at a time, don't add the test2 listeners until you remove the test1 listener. It could look like this

```
test1.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, test1OnClick);

function test1OnClick (e:MouseEvent) : void
{
    var currentMC:MovieClip = MovieClip (e.target);
    test1.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, test1OnClick);
    test2.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, test2OnClick);
    .....
}


function test2OnClick (e:MouseEvent) : void
{
    var currentMC:MovieClip = MovieClip (e.target);
    .....
}
```

Or you could do something a little more sophisticated like this

```
var currentMC:MovieClip;
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseClick);

private function mouseClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
    currentMC = e.target as MovieClip;
        //...
    }
}
```

And now you don't need a separate function for each test. How to exactly implement this depends on what you put in the `...` though.

Comment: Hello Sir, thanks for the explanation. I will work with it and see what happen. I am actually trying to develop coloring app.

Comment: For example: I want to color a cat, user need to color the cat step by step ( from head -> body -> tail). I have 3 color selection (red,blue,green) so user can click any color mc to color the cat. but for the app,user need to color the cat in order from head to tail and no color will be applied if user abuse the coloring order.

Comment: @Daniella is the Head, Body & Tail all 3 separate MCs? You can try using on the MC options like `cat_Body.mouseEnabled = false;`. Best make some functions whose job to is enable/disable each part... So when coloring the head, run the function by `allow_colour_Head();` and where elsewhere you have code `function allow_colour_Head() : void {  
cat_Head.mouseEnabled = true;
cat_Body.mouseEnabled = false;
cat_Tail.mouseEnabled = false; }`

Comment: Or even better using same above logic just remove any mouse (eg: `click`) event listeners for the body & tail. This way those parts are not responding to mouse then later you have a function for both disabling head & tail but yet enabling body MC etc etc...